# install symfony-cmf PHP Fatal error

Tags: symfony, symfony-cmf

I have installed symfony-cmf and finaly I got this error :

PHP Fatal error:  Class Sonata\MediaBundle\Block\MediaBlockService contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\BlockServiceInterface::validateBlock) in /home/jeremy/web/vendor/sonata-project/media-bundle/Block/MediaBlockService.php on line 213.

My composer.json :

```
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "~2.4",
    "doctrine/orm": "v2.4.2",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
    "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "dev-master",
    "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "2.0.*@dev",
    "jms/security-extra-bundle": "dev-master",
    "friendsofsymfony/oauth-server-bundle": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/data-fixtures": "@dev",
    "jms/serializer-bundle": "0.12.*@dev",
    "knplabs/gaufrette": "0.2.*@dev",
    "knplabs/knp-gaufrette-bundle": "dev-master",
    "vlabs/media-bundle": "v1.1.1",
    "lexik/paybox-bundle": "dev-master",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "1.1.*@dev",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "2.3.*@dev",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "2.3.*@dev",
    "simplethings/entity-audit-bundle": "0.*@dev",
    "hwi/oauth-bundle": "0.4.*@dev",
    "sonata-project/media-bundle": "2.3.*@dev",
    "tilleuls/ckeditor-sonata-media-bundle": "dev-master",
    "egeloen/ckeditor-bundle": "2.*",
    "sonata-project/formatter-bundle": "2.3.*@dev",
    "kunstmaan/voting-bundle": "2.3.*@dev",
    "fyneworks/jquery-star-rating": "dev-master",
    "friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle": "2.0.*@dev",
    "kartik-v/bootstrap-star-rating": "2.5.0",
    "symfony-cmf/create-bundle": "1.1.*",
    "jackalope/jackalope-doctrine-dbal": "1.1.*",
    "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "1.0.*",
    "symfony-cmf/symfony-cmf": "1.1.*",
    "symfony-cmf/simple-cms-bundle": "1.1.*",
    "nelmio/alice": "1.*"
```

Do yo have an idea please, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

why are you using this vendors in the dev version?
If you need to develop something using stable components, use the `@stable`

```
"sonata-project/admin-bundle": "@stable",
"sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "@stable",
```